# flutter change notifier内でのshared preferences を用いたデータの保存

Tags: flutter

モデル内でShared Preferencesを用いて、データを保存したいのですがうまくいきません。
例えば、下の例は、デフォルトのカウントアップのアプリのcounterをモデル内で保存して、アプリを終了して再度起動したときに、以前のカウンターが画面に出てくるようにしたいのですが、再起動時は0と表示されます。プラスボタンを押すと、以前の数字プラス１が表示されます。
この場合何が問題か教えていただきたいです。

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<MyHomePageModel>(
      create: (_) => MyHomePageModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyHomePageModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
      int _counter = model.getCounter();
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('FlutteR Demo Home Page'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Button());
    });
  }
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<MyHomePageModel>(context, listen: false);
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => model.addCounter(),
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePageModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _setPrefItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('counter', _counter);
  }

  void _getPrefItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _counter = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;
  }

  void addCounter() {
    _counter++;
    _setPrefItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getCounter() {
    _getPrefItems();
    return _counter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

なぜ質問文にあるような挙動になるかを説明します。

> 再起動時は0と表示されます。

MyHomePage の初回 build を考えます。このとき `model.getCounter();` は 0 を返します。なぜでしょうか？
MyHomePageModel の `getCounter` 内で `_getPrefItems` が呼ばれますが、`_getPrefItems` は非同期な関数です。`_counter = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;` の前に `return _counter;` が呼ばれます。この時点で `_counter` は初期値の 0 です。その後 MyHomePageModel の `_counter` は `prefs.getInt('counter')` がセットされますが、 `notifyListeners` がないので MyHomePage は再描画されません。

> プラスボタンを押すと、以前の数字プラス１が表示されます。

プラスボタンを押すと MyHomePageModel の `addCounter` が呼ばれます。このとき `_counter++` が実行され、次に `notifyListeners` が呼ばれます。`notifyListeners` が呼ばれると、MyHomePage は再描画され、`getCounter` は "以前の数字プラス１" を返します。

---

簡単な解決策としては `notifyListeners` を `_getPrefItems` に追加することが考えられます。

```
void _getPrefItems() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  _counter = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;
  // 追加
  notifyListeners();
}
```